# Excel SUMIFS formula based on column names

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Im trying to sum row range based on the column name values.

For example:
Columns are horizontally positioned postal code numbers
[image: Table]

and below are values, the sum i want to make is based on postal code numbers that are between 1000 and 1700.

Columns format is general and values are number and the columns are from pivot table which gets data from data model.

I tried with SUMIFS formula, but maybe im mistaken somewhere and result is 0.

```
=SUMIFS(B3:CW3;B2:CW2;">1000";B2:CW2;"<1700")
```

File: https://dox.abv.bg/download?id=193e65df0d# - Download link

Thanks in advance and have a nice day!

Comment: `">" & 1000` and `"<" & 1700`  i believe

Comment: Still returns 0, and its not like there are no columns with names between 1000 and 1700.

Comment: What type are the headers numbers or text etc

Comment: Columns are general and values are number format.

Comment: Are any of your header cells merged?

Comment: No, they arent.

Comment: You can try with `SUMPRODUCT((B3:B10)*(B2:B10>1000)*(B2:B10<1700))`, shorter ranges and formula evaluation to find the spot, where the problem arises. This is doing the same as your `SUMIFS`, but you can see, how the conditions are evaluated.

Comment: Number format doesn't mean the underlying values are numbers. The left-align suggests they are text.

Comment: Your formula looks correct, could you please share your file?

Comment: Hi, i added download link for the file, @OverflowStacker i tried your formula and result is 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your postalcode is stored as text:

[image]

We can use `NUMBERVALUE` together with `SUMPRODUCT` to make it work.

```
=SUMPRODUCT((B3:H3)*(NUMBERVALUE(B2:H2)>1000)*(NUMBERVALUE(B2:H2)<1700))
```

Result (notice that postalcode 1360 + 1528 will be summed):

[image]

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you sir and wish you all the best! :)

Comment: You too!! Good luck with the project :)!

Comment: Much appreciated!